# force cURL to send an invalid HTTP header

Tags: http, curl

How can I force cURL to send an invalid HTTP header, as follows:

```
curl -k 'https://192.168.1.1/' -H 'Host: 192.168.1.1' -H 'blah' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8'
```

When I try the above, cURL helpfully leaves out the invalid header.

Comment: I doubt that is possible. But for a specific request you do not need a full fledged protocol wrapper, you can send a raw http request via a socket from php.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can, but it's slightly more convoluted than that. curl will check that you use a colon and avoid passed in headers that don't have colons. But you can trick curl's colon check by passing in a header with embedded CRLF that then creates *two* header lines, and one of them can then be without colon.

For example like this:

```
curl -H "`printf "Foo: bar\r\nblah"`" -v localhost
```

(-v of course lets you see the actual request curl uses)

Comment: a true hack..you've restored my faith in the internet.

Comment: Or comment out the check in curl and recompile.

Comment: This is just what I needed to test my handling of invalid `Content-Length` headers; curl blocks until stdin provides enough input when specifying `-H'Content-Length: ...'` and this is the only way to force cURL _not_ to honor it. EDIT: Just realized who the answerer is. (: Makes me love it even more.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide the newline (`\n`) character as part of the header - this would cause the server to respond with `400 Bad Request`.

Your header format should look similar to this: `-H "Host: myserver\n unknown"`.

An example invocation would be:
`curl -v -H "Host: myweb\nunknown" http://localhost`.